# Using a trust to lower my property tax

Tags: taxes, property-taxes, trusts

I recently started pondering whether I could use a trust as a sort of tax dialysis instrument. Would it be possible to create a trust, sell my home to the trust for a low value and therefore lower my property value which would then dictate a lower property tax?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because asking how to commit tax fraud is off-topic for this site.

Comment: Keep in mind, property tax valuations are not typically based on what the house sold for, but rather what the city values it at [in theory as an independent fair valuation, but more commonly just a simple calculation of $ / sq ft in a given neighborhood, or something similar].

Comment: Talk to a tax attorney.  It isn't that easy.

Comment: It also would depend on jurisdiction.  In California, if I understand the Proposition 13 rules correctly, it could even increase your property tax.

Comment: How is it tax fraud if it falls within the realm of the law? I'm not asking how to break the law I'm simply asking if there are benefits to using a trust in this manner. You should read about vanguards heartbeat trades. They've been providing investors with a tax dialysis machine for many years now. Just wondering if it was the same thing for trusts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would it be possible to create a trust, sell my home to the trust for
> a low value and therefore lower my property value which would then
> dictate a lower property tax?

If a sale/change or ownership isn't done at arms length the sale information isn't used to influence assessed values of similar properties. This type of transaction generally happens when somebody is putting the property in a trust, or when a family member is being added or removed from the title. In my county you can see a note to this on some transactions on the tax assessment website.

If they won't use the transaction for other similar properties they won't use it for setting the asses value of your property.